# How to Launch and debug Ghidra from Eclipse with two Modules I'm developing at the same time?

Tags: debugging, java, ghidra, development

Ghidra comes with its own Eclipse extensions that allows you to develop new Scripts and Modules for Ghidra.

I'm working on several new Modules for Ghidra that will work together. But I've basically never used Java or Eclipse before.

Normally you're just working on one Module at a time and to test it you launch it in debug mode from the Eclipse IDE.

But Ghidra creates one Configuration for each project and will only include the current Module. Everything in your other Modules won't be linked in to Ghidra, even if you've had all their files open in the IDE and you're switching between them, you can only debug with one present at a time.

How can I get Ghidra to launch with three Modules I'm working on all together?

I've been going through the configuration dialogs and I've Googled various wordings of the problem in relation to Ghidra, in relation to Eclipse, and both together, to no avail.

I did clone one of the configurations and add the other modules' projects to that configuration in the "classpath" window, but on launching, only the main module is there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out by trial and error.

From the main Eclipse window:

1. Click on the dropdown arrow on the "Debug As..." button in the toolbar.
2. Select "Debug Configurations..."
   [image: Eclipse "Debug As..." Toolbar]

In the Configuration Editor:

1. You can edit your existing Ghidra configuration for your project or you can make a duplicate of it like I did. Then select that project in the left side.
2. On the right side click on the "Classpath" tab.
3. You will see your main project at the top of the list under the "Bootstrap Entries" section. Collapse this section.
4. You will see there is another section below, currently empty, named "User Entries".
5. Click on the "Add Projects..." button to the right.
6. Select your other existing project(s).

That's it. You'll now get the functionality from the main project and the other projects together. You can now verify that by clicking on "Debug" in the bottom right.

[image: Eclipse Configuration Editor]